# Disable retrying of POST request via AJAX if connection was dropped

Tags: apache, http, browser

### Problem

Sometimes important HTTP POST requests sent with AJAX got duplicated so several entries of the same data got created in the production database, that is of course not supposed by users.

What is important is that users have a poor internet connection and this request is taking a long time (9-20 seconds). We can't reduce this time because it is the requirements of business logic.

Requests are sent with http, not https.

### Details

We have Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) with PHP module loaded and two frontends: one for desktop (AngularJS) and one for mobile (React) devices. AngularJS is sending requests with the `$http` service, and React is using `whatwg-fetch` (tried `whatwg-fetch-timeout` also).

We know from Apache access.log and PHP logs that the same request is coming from the client several times and PHP processes them without the errors. But! These requests have response with 200 status code, %b > 0, and %O = 0, that means request is aborted before a response is sent ([Apache logging format docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html])).

### Reproduce

So we tried to reproduce and the same happens sometimes. The following case  is just a reproduced case, but this happens on mobile devices (iPhones and Android phones) with different browsers installed. Also, we have repeated it in the Firefox under Windows.

Environment: Windows; both Chrome and Firefox; React frontend version; **no proxy** used.

That's what we found out: Google Chrome identifies the request as "Stalled", but is internally trying to send the request multiple times (and it is received and processed on the server actually), because it got the network error (`ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`). Only when the browser succeeded to fetch the response, it stops sending the repeating requests.

#### Gathered info

1. URL_REQUEST [event log](https://pastebin.com/ckH7zW66) from chrome://net-internals/help.html#events (headers are also available there)
2. Google Chrome dev tools request screenshots:

   - [Headers tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Feysz.jpg)
   - [Timeline tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nD1N.jpg)

---

I personally can't reproduce this even once and I suppose a good internet connection is a reason for this.

I have googled a lot and even found some similar Chromium bugs, but nothing exactly about this problem.

Thank you in advance for any useful information.

I am also not pretty sure which tags should I set for this question, so if I should add or remove some, please tell me.